# cant login to gcloud shell exec: fish: not found

Tags: gcloud

so i added

```
exec fish
```

in .bashrc

now i cant login

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to google.
Use “gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]” to change to a different project.
bash: exec: fish: not found
Connection to <ip> closed.
```

i have tried this

```
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --authorize-session --command "bash --norc"
```

but this just hangs and does nothing

however i did install the fish shell when i was logged last time

Comment: revert back to the default shell, bash, and then run fish manually when you need it.

Comment: yes but i have to login first i can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so when i did

```
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --authorize-session --command "bash --norc"
```

it started the shell but you could not do anything with it but it was running the bash shell although

now as i said the main problem was caused by .bashrc simply removing it was the best option

```
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --authorize-session --command "rm .bashrc"
gcloud cloud-shell ssh
```